# AWS s3 cross-account policy to ensure that all accounts can read

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have multiple AWS accounts.  Let's say account A, B and C, with IAM users IA, IB and IC.  There's an S3 bucket in B, S3B.  I have this configured so that if IB puts a file in S3B, all three users can read it.  I've been able to further configure it such that IA and IC can upload -- but then only they can read those files.  I was able to put a restriction on it such that IA and IC must grant IB permissions to read as well -- however, granting this still doesn't allow the other of IA or IC to read it, and requires the right call from the client code.

Is there any way to allow IA and IC to upload and automatically grant permissions such that all three accounts have read access?

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One IAM Role across multiple AWS accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988173/one-iam-role-across-multiple-aws-accounts)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this through Bucket Policies which are managed at the S3 Bucket level and are separate from Identity Access Management (IAM). The union of access between IAM, Bucket Policies, and Object Access Controls (File/Object Level) will grant the Principal (User or Group) access. Make sure there are no explicit denies as any explicit deny will trump any access permissions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html

Comment: I don't believe it's quite so straightforward, when the constraints of the question are fully considered.  If A owns the bucket and B uploads an object, then B owns the object and A's bucket ownership does not entitle A to grant access to the object to C.  The `bucket-owner-full-control` canned ACL may allow some override by A but may not allow A to do anything via policy to expose B's object in A's bucket to C.

Comment: I think its achievable via ACL. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html

Comment: Under the grantee section, kindly look there. I believe giving READ and READ_ACP permissions via object ACL does it

Comment: Yes, but that shifts the burden to the object creator, not the bucket owner via the bucket policy.

Comment: Per the docs, ACLs can be applied to the bucket and the object level. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#sample-acl

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather confusing, but I shall assume that you are asking **how to permit users in other AWS accounts access to an Amazon S3 bucket** (including creation and reading of files).

You have:

- User-A in Account-A
- Bucket-B in Account-B

First, you will need to add a policy to Account B that permits access by User-A. It would look something like:

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*"
            ],
            "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::<Account-A>:user/User-A"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that this policy is on Bucket-B in Account-B, but it is granting access to User-A in Account-A.

Second, User-A requires permission to use S3. This might already be granted to the user, but it's worth mentioning because they need to be granted permission to actually call S3. Here is a sample of a policy they would need:

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

To clarify: If they already have a policy that lets them call S3 on any bucket (eg `s3:*` on `Resource: *`), then they will not need the above policy since they already have permissions to call S3.

**But...**

If you are actually trying to limit things so that files uploaded by User-A are read-only to User-B and files created by User-B are read-only to User-A, this is **a lot harder** and is best avoided unless you write your own management application or use separate paths to control permissions.